# How do i set a static route to bypass VPN for a website using my ipv6 address?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipv6, static-routes

So i use a tracker which doesnt allow browsing of its site using a vpn.  It is advised to add a persistent route to circumvent and allow browsing while connected to a vpn which I have done using

```
route –p add <their ipv4 address> <my gateway ipv4 address>
```

I have recently enabled ipv6 in my gateway, and as such I'm trying to do the same for ipv6.  operating under the assumption its the same

```
route –p add <their ipv4 address> <my gateway **ipv6** address>
```

I only need to know how to obtain the exact address for the latter value.  If I'm off base, please advise.   I'm just now even peeking at ipv6 and it has my head spinning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you're trying to do the same for IPv6, then `<their ipv4 address>` also needs to be IPv6. (If the website doesn't *have* an IPv6 address, then there's no point in this whole exercise – just use an IPv4 route as you previously did.)

<sup>(In theory, it should be completely possible to use an IPv6 gateway address for an IPv4 route or vice versa – and indeed Linux allows such combinations – but this is very rarely *useful*.)</sup>

Second, note that there can be at least *two* 'gateway' addresses representing the same router – a link-local `fe80::xxx` address and a global `2xxx::yz` address. Some methods listed below will give you a link-local address, others will give you a global address; either is fine when used as a route 'gateway'.

---

The easiest way is to just look in `ipconfig`, where your router's IP address is simply labelled as "Default Gateway":

```
C:\> ipconfig

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   [...]
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.213
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::6e3b:6bff:fe4c:3ba1%4
                                       192.168.1.254
```

Alternatively you can take a look at your current routing table using `route print -6` and use the gateway (and interface index) from the `::/0` route:

```
C:\> route print -6
IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  4    281 ::/0                     fe80::6e3b:6bff:fe4c:3ba1
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  4     26 2a06:e881:108::/48       2a06:e881:108:2::1
...
```

Note the interface index `4` in both examples (it's often attached to the address after a % sign). Because the gateway here is a link-local address using the generic 'fe80' prefix, the OS may need to be told *which* link (interface) it corresponds to.

```
route add 2001:db8::/48 fe80::6e3b:6bff:fe4c:3ba1%4
-or-
route add 2001:db8::/48 fe80::6e3b:6bff:fe4c:3ba1 if 4
```

The third method is to look at your router's settings screen. Depends on model, but it *will* usually have some place where it shows its own LAN addresses.

Comment: excellent answer, gets me much more shored up as far as ipv6 goes.  Thank you for your time!